# how to dynamically add rows to a GridView through a DataTable without affecting any table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have to show a gridview in my page which doesn't concerns any table to be bound with it. Still it should store one Tax detail per row, as entered by user. Following is the image which will clarify what problem I'm facing.[image: Dynamic Gridview]

1. The gridview shown above should not show any records at first except the footer template of two textboxes and an Add New Record Button, when you are upto add any record.
2. Once clicked on Add New Record button it should show a row without action column.
3. (I'm having quite a hard time here)Once clicked on Add/Insert Button(separate from the gridview) store the entered record somehow.
4. Then I have to show the record in ***Another*** concrete GridView with Edit Button.
5. Once I click on edit button, control should return to my dynamic gridview page. Here, my dynamic gridview will show previously entered record with action column containing a delete button.

Can you Help Me? I don't want help with the code. Just point me in the right direction(s), please.

Comment: Of course we can't help with code. You haven't given us any to begin with. Would you mind reading the [FAQ] and [ask]?

Comment: @Marco Sorry if I'm mistaken, but I don't want help with the code, Just a way or directions on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try this.

```
private DataTable AddEmptyRow()
{
    DataTable originalDataTable = GetItems();
    DataTable newDataTable = originalDataTable.Clone();

    string category = originalDataTable.Rows[0][2].ToString();
    foreach (DataRow dRow in originalDataTable.Rows)
    {
        if (category != dRow[2].ToString())
        {
            DataRow newDataRow = newDataTable.NewRow();
            newDataTable.Rows.Add(newDataRow);
            category = dRow[2].ToString();
        }
        newDataTable.ImportRow(dRow);
    }
    return newDataTable;
}
```

You can add row by using `DataRow newDataRow = newDataTable.NewRow();`.